# __debugbreak and int3 instruction

Tags: debugging, x86, gdb, interrupt

`jmp 1f
push %eax
1:
movl $100, (%eax)
call __debugbreak
int3
ret`

Suppose we want to put a breakpoint on push %eax instruction. Can we do it
by rewriting push %eax with call debugbreak? What is the problem with the above approach? Why does rewriting with int3 work in this case?

Comment: `__debugbreak` is used to *statically* emit a breakpoint  (i.e. in a debug build when an assertion fails). `int3` is equivalent on x86 but is less portable. `int3` is used by the debugger to place breakpoints dynamically because it can be encoded in only one byte `0xCC` and so it's easy to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int3` is a single-byte instruction (and so is the `push` in this case). `call` isn't. You `jmp` will jump into the "middle" of `call` if you overwrite your `push` with `call` instead of `int3`.
But unless there's a way to reach the `push` (I see no label before it to jump/call to), putting a breakpoint on `push` is useless, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by jmp will jump into the "middle" of call? What is jmp 1f exactly doing here? (I am new to assembly language).

Comment: @anandthegreat `jmp 1f` jumps forward to the nearest label `1`.

Comment: @anandthegreat If you have an instruction that is longer than one byte and if you jump not to the first byte of it, you sort of jump into the middle of it. The problem is that the CPU doesn't know what is (or was supposed to be) there at the beginning, before this middle, so it decodes the remainder of that instruction as a different instruction because it "thinks" that's where the new instruction starts.